# Make 2 rows of item into 1 row, side-by side

Tags: css

The code is:

```
<div class="mf-product-price-box">
  <span class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-price-amount.amount">
    <div class="item-sold">
      <span class="items-sold-texts">1 item sold</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

My question is, how to combine these 2 rows into 1 rows, with side-to-side?
[image]

Comment: There are so many possible options: float, flexbox or grid. Pick one.

Comment: Thank you sir. Currently I'm stuck here and don't know what to do. I am a beginner in the CSS. This complexity in my problem make my website stuck.

Could you demonstrate any other way on this matter sir?

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this. I prefer to use flexbox in such cases. Let me know if it helped.

```css
.mf-product-price-box {
  width: 26rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #ddd;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex; /* You need this... */
  justify-content: space-between; /* and this */
}
```

```html
<div class="mf-product-price-box">
  <span class="price">RM 360.00</span>
  <span class="woocommerce-price-amount.amount">
    <div class="item-sold">
      <span class="items-sold-texts">1 item sold</span>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work sir. Under the div, it has two different element which is span and another div, How to combine them?

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work.. The line become like this [link] (https://imgur.com/IkE1AZ4)

Comment: Of course, you don't have enough space for sold items. In this case, is better to show one card per row instead of two.

Comment: I see. Then I'll leave it just like that. Anyway, thanks for the help from the beginning sir. You have been amazing!